# How do I add an array into an other array from a Model?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to add packages into the category array, Only in the first category it works like I want it to work but in the second and thrid category it doesn't have an array format anymore. (see example below)

I'm doing it like this because a store has categories and servers but a package can be in mutiple servers and the category is connected to the store. And I only want to display the category when it has at least one package in the server

```
[
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Category1",
    "packages": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Package1",
        "minecraft_item": "3",
        "price": "4.43",
        "category_id": 7,
        "position": 0,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": "2020-12-14T08:49:59.000000Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Category2",
    "packages": {
      "1": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Package2",
        "minecraft_item": "3",
        "price": "4.43",
        "category_id": 8,
        "position": 0,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": "2020-12-14T08:49:59.000000Z"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Category3",
    "packages": {
      "2": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Package3",
        "minecraft_item": "WOOD",
        "price": "12",
        "category_id": 9,
        "position": 0,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": "2020-12-14T08:49:59.000000Z"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Code:

```
        $categories = Category::where('store_id', $server->store->id)->get();
        $array = [];
        foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
            $packages = Server::find($server->id)->packages->where('category_id', $category->id);
            if ($packages->first()) {
                $array[$key]['id'] = $category->id;
                $array[$key]['name'] = $category->name;
                $array[$key]['packages'] = $packages;
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships - describes the relations in Laravel.
In your case add inside your `Category` model:

```
public function packages()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Package::class);
}
```

And then:

```
$categories = Category::where('store_id', $server->store->id)->whereHas('packages')
->select(['id', 'name']
->with(['packages']
->get();
```